# Calendar Reminders have stopped showing

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook-2011

Calendar Reminders have stopped showing.  They were working up to a couple of days ago but now they do not appear.  I have tried turning them on and off and quitting and reopening MS Outlook.

Comment: Does it work if you start it from **/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Office/Office Addins/office reminders** ?

Comment: Did you
- check your notification settings?
- log out and log in?
- restart your computer? If nothing helps, your best try is reinstalling, because, you know, it's microsoft software.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to just the standard calendar entries or actual reminders? If it's just calendar entries then re sync your mail account with Calendar. Calendar>Preferences>Accounts>Hit the minus on the account then re add it. I had the same issue last week, hope it helps!